# Best query to remove non-breaking spaces from a single column in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column that holds some values. This is an example value:

```
This is hidden in the string
```

This is actually `ThisU+A0is·hidden·in·the·string`

I want to get rid of the non-breaking spaces for a single column, so the U+A0 gets replaced by regular spaces.

What is the best way to do this without breaking anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` in postgresql

```
select
   replace('ThisU+A0is·hidden·in·the·string', 'U+A0', ' ') as new_string
from yourTable
```